# OWL carousel not working in iframe at iphone & ipad

Tags: jquery, iframe, owl-carousel

OWL carousel using version is 2.3.4. Working android iframe and webs version good but when I am using iPhone or iPpad not working its showing entire width.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution here is the solution.

```
div.owl-carousel { width: 1px; min-width: 100%; *width: 100%; }
```